# Date part of a DateTime field for comparison

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-3.5, datetime-comparison

I'm using [Superlist](http://superlist.codeplex.com) with a due date column (SQL `DateTime`) as a column in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

I need, in order to the final user be able to sort by this column, to use just the DATE part of the column. The problem is that if I set the `DueDate.Date` value, it shows the time as `00:00:00`, and if I set as `DueDate.ToShortDateString()` the issue is that `February 1st` happens before `January 31` in the ascending order.

Is there ***ANY*** way to show just the date without converting it as a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing the idea of a structure and a string.  When you say "Show Date", you are talking about interpreting the `DateTime` struct as a string...for your viewing.

So the answer to your question is no, there is no way to show *anything* about a `DateTime` without converting it first to a `string`.

If you're talking about retrieving just the date part of the `DateTime` struct, then what you have described is how it works.  Because a **Date** is really just the `DateTime` with a zeroed out **Time** portion.

Comment: That was the doubt. Thanks for your fast response. I will try to make a comparable delegate getting two strings but comparing them in a Date converted value. Wish me luck!

Answer (score 1):

Shark is correct about the generic question, but to show as a sortable string:

```
mydate.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd");
```

Comment: Thanks @Zach Green. But is not possible here (in Uruguay) to show dates in any format but "dd/mm/yyyy".